# File upload form does not work with large files

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have a pretty standard upload form. A few text inputs, a file upload input, a reCAPTCHA, and a submit button.

Under normal use, I can upload a small file just fine. The form data is redirected to the page in the action attribute, and a while bunch of things are done in the PHP and SQL that handles the uploads.

However, when trying to upload a 40 MB file, it simply does not work. At first, I thought it was the CAPTCHA, since it gave me errors about failing to type in the correct words. After disabling the CAPTCHA, I found that the variables that defined all my $_POST['input'] were not being passed through. I would get PHP errors such as:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in /var/www/upload.php on line 18
```

Where line 18 is `$name=$_POST['name'];`

I would get one of these for every input in my form.

This is telling me that the POST is not being set because the form is not working when it is sending large files, so my question is simply...Why? And of course, what's the solution?

EDIT: Relevant code:

Submit form:

```
<form action="/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input class="text" type="text" name="name">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="text" type="email" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $content['SubmitFormEmailPlaceholder'];?>">
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input class="text" type="text" name="url" placeholder="http://">
        </li>
        <li>
            <textarea class="text" name="notes" rows="5"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <?php
                require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/recaptchalib.php');
                $publickey = "key";
                echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
            ?>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Upload code:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    //echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey="key";
    $resp=recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if(!$resp->is_valid){
        echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadCaptcha']."<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
    }else{
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        if(empty($name)){
            echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadName']."<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
        }elseif(empty($email)){
            echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadEmail']."<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
        }else{
            $url=$_POST['url'];
            $notes=$_POST['notes'];
            $timedate=date('YmdHis');
            $dbHandle=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=upload;","user","password",array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));
            $dbHandle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $query=$dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO `data` (approved,name,email,fileid,url,notes,timedate,viewcount) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $types=array(
                'jpg','jpeg','gif','png',
                'mp3','wma','wav','ogg','aac','flac',
                'avi','wmv','mov','ogg','webm','mpg','mpeg','mp4'
            );
            $filechk=(isset($_FILES['file']) && !empty($_FILES['file']['name']));
            $urlchk=(isset($url) && !empty($url));
            if(!$filechk ^ $urlchk){
                echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadFileURL']."<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
            }elseif($filechk){
                $filesize=(75*1024*1024);
                $up_path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/resources/uploads/';
                $filename=$timedate.$_FILES['file']['name'];
                $ex=explode(".",$filename);
                $ext=strtolower(end($ex));
                if(file_exists($up_path.$filename)) {
                    $filename=$timedate.'Duplicate.'.$ext;
                }
                if(!in_array($ext,$types)){
                    echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadFileType']."<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
                }elseif(filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])>$filesize){
                    echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadFileSize'].($filesize/1024/1024)." MB<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
                }elseif(!is_writable($up_path)){
                    echo "<h1>".$content['UploadError']."</h1>".$content['UploadWriteError']."<br><br>".$content['UploadReturn'];
                }elseif(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$up_path.$filename)){
                    $fileid=$filename;
                    $url=null;
                    $query->execute(array('N',$name,$email,$fileid,$url,$notes,$timedate,'0'));
                    echo "<h1>".$content['UploadSuccess']."</h1>".$content['UploadHomepage'];
                }else{
                    echo "<h1>".$content['UploadUnknownError']."</h1>".$content['UploadReturn'];
                }
            }else{
                $fileid=null;
                $query->execute(array('N',$name,$email,$fileid,$url,$notes,$timedate,'0'));
                echo "<h1>".$content['UploadSuccess']."</h1>".$content['UploadHomepage'];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What's the specified file size in your php.ini for file uploads? See here: https://drupal.org/node/97193

Comment: Initially 2M, though I just increased that limit with your link and the other answer here. So far still not working, even after restarting apache2

Comment: Are you able to upload small files? At least to determine there's not a bigger issue with your server config

Answer (score 6):

Try and increase your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file. Set them both to 50M to be sure.

You should restart apache after changing this, too. It depends on your setup, so replace pathToApache with the path to apache on your server;

```
sudo /etc/pathToApache/apache2 restart
```

[Apache start/restart/stop docs.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html)

Comment: I put them both to 200M, saved, and restarted apache2. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you running a framework or CMS? They may have custom PHP attributes or entries in the .htaccess files which restrict this, too.

Comment: Everything is built from scratch and the server is my own. The PHP and apache settings are stock (well, excluding the newly changed size limits)

Comment: Whelp you'll need to look at the error codes generated when you try, as described by @skrilled.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll get around to it in an hour or so. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your php web server config file. so u must change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize to 100  in php.ini file in your server. if you don't have permission to change it in your server, so in your htaccess file add this lines :

```
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better answer than simply updating your php.ini max_upload_filesize  is to actually code with the expectation that errors might happen, and handle them appropriately. Upping your file size is a bandaid to an ultimately larger problem in which you are expecting that the world is perfect and your code will always run flawlessly under all test cases.

One way of achieving said better method:

```
if($_FILES['fileVarName']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
  // we had an error uploading the file, let's handle it like a boss
}
```

Here is a list of possible errors: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I put `echo $_FILES['file']['error'];` at the top of my action file's code. I got the same error regarding an undefined index ('file' is the name of the file selection input. EDIT: It returns 0 for the files that are uploading properly, which of course, is as it should be.

Comment: can you edit your question and show the code used for the form that is posting said data.

Comment: Done. I've also included the upload code, in case there might be something wrong on that end.